# How do I link CSS files to my view in Rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

How do I link my css stylesheet to my html file. I am using rails to generate an application, but the file structure is still quite confusing. I have a directory for stylesheets in assets, but I don't know how to link them. Here is what my index.html file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Stylish Portfolio - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/stylish-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#top"  onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Start Bootstrap</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#top" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#about" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#services" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#portfolio" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header id="top" class="header">
        <div class="text-vertical-center">
            <h1>Start Bootstrap</h1>
            <h3>Free Bootstrap Themes &amp; Templates</h3>
            <br>
            <a href="#about" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Find Out More</a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- About -->
    <section id="about" class="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Stylish Portfolio is the perfect theme for your next project!</h2>
                    <p class="lead">This theme features some wonderful photography courtesy of <a target="_blank" href="http://join.deathtothestockphoto.com/">Death to the Stock Photo</a>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </section>

    <!-- Services -->
    <!-- The circle icons use Font Awesome's stacked icon classes. For more information, visit http://fontawesome.io/examples/ -->
    <section id="services" class="services bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <h2>Our Services</h2>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong>Service Name</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-compass fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong>Service Name</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-flask fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong>Service Name</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-shield fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                            </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong>Service Name</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </section>

    <!-- Callout -->
    <aside class="callout">
        <div class="text-vertical-center">
            <h1>Vertically Centered Text</h1>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <!-- Portfolio -->
    <section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                    <h2>Our Work</h2>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-1.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-2.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-3.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="portfolio-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-4.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">View More Items</a>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </section>

    <!-- Call to Action -->
    <aside class="call-to-action bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h3>The buttons below are impossible to resist.</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-light">Click Me!</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark">Look at Me!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <!-- Map -->
    <section id="contact" class="map">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
        <br />
        <small>
            <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A"></a>
        </small>
        </iframe>
    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                    <h4><strong>Start Bootstrap</strong>
                    </h4>
                    <p>3481 Melrose Place<br>Beverly Hills, CA 90210</p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></i> (123) 456-7890</li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i>  <a href="mailto:name@example.com">name@example.com</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <p class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script>
    // Closes the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });

    // Opens the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });

    // Scrolls to the selected menu item on the page
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I commented the link that I need help with such as the Bootstrap Core CSS, and custom CSS.

Comment: include those required name files inside `application.js` and `application.css`, after all it will be automatically linked with your view.

Comment: But isn't there a way to link external stylesheets...I don't want to lump it all together to application

Answer (score 2):

Open your `application.html.erb` file and put this line of code together with existing tag :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %>
// put another external link 
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'externalFilePath...' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'externalFilePath...' %>
```

You might want read **[this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html)** also.

Answer (score 1):

From Section 3.1.3: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html:

> The stylesheet_link_tag helper returns an HTML  tag for each
>   source provided.
>
> If you are using Rails with the "Asset Pipeline" enabled, this helper
>   will generate a link to /assets/stylesheets/. This link is then
>   processed by the Sprockets gem. A stylesheet file can be stored in one
>   of three locations: app/assets, lib/assets or vendor/assets.

Answer (score 1):

You can call all stylesheets with:  found in (app/views/layouts/application.html.erb)

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

or create a separate directory for your external stylesheet

asset::your_external_css::new_sytle

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "your_external_css/new_style" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need separate libraries editable files, the Rails "Asset Pipeline" all in one file called application.css or aplication.js

you need only request the files:

Application.css.scss

```
    @import 'bootstrap';           #vendor/assets
    @import 'bootstrap_overrides';
    @import 'icons';
    @import 'colors';
    @import 'layout';
    @import 'naked';
    @import 'pages';
```

application_layout.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

if you need created other file when rails compile, Add this function in your config/application.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(
  yourfile.css
)
```

in your layout

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "yourfile", :media => "all" %>
```

and you need created a file in assents/stylesheets/yourfile.css.scss

The Ruby pipeline guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

I know it cant be quite confusing, here is what you can do. Add these lines into your application.css file.

```
 /*
 *= require stylesheet
 */
```

Or

```
/*
*= require stylesheet.css
*/
```